# Upper and lower darboux sum

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, improper-integrals, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

I have recently been going through some questions on Riemann integration.I got stuck in one of those questions which happen to be a multiple-select question. It says that:

> Let $f$ be a continuously differentiable real-valued function on $[a,b]$ such that $\left\lvert f'(x)\right\rvert\le k$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$. Then for any partition $P$ of $[a,b]$, which of the following is/are correct?

1. $\left\lvert L(f,P)\right\rvert\le k(b-a) \le \left\lvert U(f,P)\right\rvert$
2. $U(f,P)-L(f,P) \le k(b-a)$
3. $U(f,P)-L(f,P) \le k \left\lVert P\right\rVert$ where $\left\lVert P\right\rVert$ is the norm of partition $P$
4. $U(f,P)-L(f,P )\le k\left\lVert P\right\rVert(b-a)$

This is what I have done so far:

Since $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ therefore by mean-value theorem there exists a $c$ in $(a,b)$ such that $f'(c) = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$.

And then by the hypothesis we obtain that $\left\lvert f(b)-f(a)\right\rvert\le k(b-a)$.

Now how should I proceed?

Comment: Are you sure this is the statement of the exercise? Because for a constant function we may take $k=0$, and then (1) is false.

Comment: It is not a statement.It is a multiple-select question.We have to choose correct options.

Comment: Ah, I see.${}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $$P=(x_i)_{i=0,n}$$

then

$$U(f,P)-L(f,P)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(M_i-m_i)(x_{i+1}-x_i)$$
where
$$M_i=\sup_{[x_i,x_{i+1}]}f \; \; and $$
$$m_i=\inf_{[x_i,x_{i+1}]  } f .$$
$f $ is continuous at $ [x_i,x_{i+1}] $, thus
$$M_i=f(b_i), \; and \; m_i=f(a_i)$$

with $(a_i,b_i)\in [x_i,x_{i+1}]^2$.

Wlog, we assume that $a_i<b_i$.

$f $ is continuous at $[a_i,b_i]$ and differentiable at $ (a_i,b_i) $, then by MVT, 
$$M_i-m_i=f(b_i)-f(a_i)=(b_i-a_i)f'(c_i)$$

with $b_i-a_i\le x_{i+1}-x_i\le ||P||$.
therefore

$$M_i-m_i\le ||P||k$$
and finally
$$U(f,P)-L(f,P)\le k||P||(b-a)$$

Comment: But why is (b1-a1)+(b2-a2)+...(bn-an)<=(b-a)?

Comment: @Gitika No, $b_i-a_i\le ||P|| and $x_1-x_0+(x_2-x_1)+...(b-x_{n-1})=b-a$.

Comment: Why is bi-ai<=||P||?..Are they partition points?

Comment: $|b_i-a_i|\le |x_{i+1}-x_i|\le ||P||. Because $x_i\le a_i\le b_i \le x_{i+1}$.

Comment: Oh..ok ok..thank you

Comment: How to check second and third option?

Comment: And you haven't written this..But i still wanted to ask that can we prove that U(f,P)-L(f,P)<=||P||{f(b)-f(a)}?..I saw it written somewhere.

Comment: Okay..I have discarded the other options..thanks!

Comment: @Gitika Okay.{}{}{}{}